# C programming language excercise1-18

Tags: c, arrays, function

Hi guys i am reading The C programming language by Kernighan and Ritchie and trying to solve along the questions. This program is supposed to eliminate all the blanks and tabs from the end of the input lines but its not working. 
**I have added comments to the section of code i am having problems with**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
int getline(char line[], int max);
void copy(char to[], char frm[]);
int main(void) {
    int maxLen=0;
    int currLen;    
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longestLine[MAXLINE];
    while((currLen=getline(line,MAXLINE)) > 0){
        if(currLen > maxLen){
            maxLen = currLen;
            copy(longestLine, line);
        }
    }
    if(maxLen>0){
        printf("%d\n", maxLen);
        printf("%s", longestLine);
    }
    return 0;
}
int getline(char line[], int max){
    int c,i;
    for(i=0;i<max-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';i++){
        line[i] = c;
    }
    if(c == '\n'){

        /* This is the logic i added to take care of the trailing 
        spaces and tabs. Rest of the program is same as the book
        Its still counting spaces at the end of line when variable maxLen is 
        printed in the main function, would like to know if the logic is 
        erronous*/

        while(line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\t'){
            i--;
        }

        line[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
void copy(char to[], char from[]){
    int i=0;
    while((to[i]=from[i])!='\0'){
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a few `printf` to the code, and show the value of `i` and `c` at various points. Or use a debugger to step through the code, while watching `i` and `c`.

Comment: An [mcve] (at least for an input->output program) should be accompanied by sample input, output and different desired output. Please provide several sets of them and elaborate the mentioned details of your problem referring to those examples.

Comment: Are you not getting `"error: conflicting types for ‘getline’"` compiler warnings?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why would they get that?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am getting that error when i tried compiling on linux and some other online compiler but couple of them went ahead with the execution without that error. Could you please shed some light on that

Comment: @Yunnosch Program displays the count of the characters in a line and the line itself, its counting trailing spaces in the count as well. shouldn't this piece of code  while(line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\t'){ i--;} take care of the trailing spaces?

Comment: I have added comments to point out the part of code that is not working.

Comment: Please give examples of input, output and desired output - instead of describing it.

Comment: @Yunnosch input = "Test line "  ,actual output = 10 ,expected output = 9 . It should ideally stop counting the characters after the last 'e' and omit any spaces or tabs that follows

Comment: Why do you expect an output of "9"? You code should output a number and the longest line, shouldn't it? Your printf does not allow to tell a "Test line \n" from a "Test line\n". Please edit delimiters, e.g. "<Test line >\n" or "<Test line>\n". That would allow to tell "Test line", "Test line ", "Test line\n" and "Test line \n" apart.

Comment: Why do you expect an output of "9"? You code should output a number and the longest line, shouldn't it? Your printf does not allow to tell a "Test line \n" from a "Test line\". Please edit delimiters, e.g. "<Test line >\n" or "<Test line>\n". That would allow to tell "Test line", "Test line ", "Test line\n" and "Test line \n" apart.

Comment: @Yunnosch, My guess is you haven't read the code. I added some logic to the function getLine() for removing the extra spaces in the end. Check the comments in my code above.

Comment: I read this code `printf("%d\n", maxLen);
        printf("%s", longestLine);` and expect it to print a number and a string. I wonder why you expect a number but not a string.

Comment: You will get the conflicting types error on a Posix system (like linux). `getline` is a Posix function. It's not mentioned in the C standard.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @Yunnosch, i expect it to print a string. Perhaps i worded it wrong, i dont have problem with the string only with the value of maxLen variable. But i have resolved the mistake, it comes from the value of i.

Comment: If you found a solution but none of the answers below covers it, then please make your own answer, in order to help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, your program is returning the longest line entered, and does not eliminate blanks or tabs.

you are welcome to see the solution the link below:
[solution to 1-18](http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/Ex_1.18_remtrailbt.html)

I hope this helped
good luck

Comment: instead of writing a link to the solution, publish partially your solution here

Comment: @gutzcha Thanks for your help, i am under the impression my code logic should work. I dont want to look at another solution untill i figure out the problem with my logic

Answer (score 0):

### First, let's take a look at your output:

```
if(maxLen>0){
        printf("%d\n", maxLen);
        printf("%s", longestLine);
}
```

This part isn't in any loop and does not contain any loop, so it prints just one line. However, the program should print all the lines. Therefore, your code that prints lines should be in a loop similar to the code that gets a line. They could be in the same loop, like this:

```
while there is text left
    get line
    removing the spaces
    print line
end loop
```

Or in different loops. Actually, I think you misunderstood the exercise, because it's printing the longest one, and that cleary seems to be your intention going by your code.

### Deleting the whitespace

It seems that this is where you're trying to delete the whitespace:

```
while(line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\t'){
    i--;
}
```

Note that the `i` you're using here is **not** the `i` from this line:

```
for(i=0;i<max-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';i++){
```

Instead, it's the `i` from this line:

```
int c,i;
```

This is because in `for(i=0; ...` you're defining another `i` so that one is in scope for the loop. The first `i` isn't touched in that loop and is still uninitialized when you try to delete the whitespace. So `line[i]` is undefined behavior and will most likely just crash your program. And even if it doesn't, it will just read a rubbish value, see if it coincidentally translates to `' '` or `'\t'` and then either not do anything, or decrease `i` and try again.

My suggestion to you is that you should try to solve the exercise incrementally. The task can be split in multiple parts:

- Removing trailing whitespace from a line
- Reading in the input

Do one after another. First, you write a program that takes one hardcoded line and removes the trailing whitespace and prints it. Then, when that works, you modify it to work with not one line, but with all the input lines. This way you don't have multiple parts that aren't working, but instead you can focus on doing one part at a time. It's easier to write software this way.

Comment: There's only one `i` in the `getline` function, and it's declared on this line: `int c,i;` The `for` loop won't create a new variable unless you tell it to, e.g. `for (int i`

Comment: @Blaze since i never declared i in the loop, i assumed it would just use the one that i have already declared at the start of the program. If they are in a different scope, how is the function returning the length of the string?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys. Problem was with the value of i in function getLine. Here is the solution:

```
int getline(char line[], int max){
    int c,i;
    for(i=0;i<max-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';i++){
        line[i] = c;
    }

    i--; /* This line is the fix, value of i is incremented before termination of the 
             loop, so decrement it to point to the last character in the array */

    while(line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\b'){
        i--;
    }
    if(c == '\n'){
        line[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```